# Android Facebook sharing dialog disappears after few seconds for non developer accounts

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have added Facebook wall post feature in my android app using below code, but when i try to post data the share dialog appears for few seconds and then it disappears. I am getting error message in FacebookDialog.Callback onError method as "Failed to generate preview for user"  and exception in my logcat as "ApiException: [code] 100 [message]: (#100) App 12345 is not allowed to create actions of type namespace_asd:xyz for user 54321" :

```
    OpenGraphObject obj = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost(“abc”);
    obj.setProperty(
            "title",
            “message goes here“);
    obj.setType(“namespace_asd:xyz”);


    List<Bitmap> imageArr = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    imageArr.add(bmp1);

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("abc", obj);
    action.setType(“namespace_asd:xyz”);


    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "abc").setImageAttachmentsForObject("abc", imageArr,
            true).build();

    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

The sharing works only with developer accounts but not with other accounts. I am done with approval of the required permissions(i.e publish_actions) from Facebook submission process.

Also i have enabled check for general public features availability in Status & Review section.

Please help....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Ming Li and everyone for helping, I got approved of open graph object and now a non developer user can also post of Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

When your application is in sandbox/development mode you can not perform any api call for other user. Other user can use your app, when your is public for other user. To test your app for other user, add the user as a tester, developer or admin. See [details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/)

Note : your app is publicly accessible for other user when your app is approved by the facebook store after reviewing your app. To submit your app for review [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

Comment: My app is available for public....i already added in description that "Also i have enabled check for general public features availability in Status & Review section."

Comment: My app is already done with the submission and got approved of "publish_actions" permission.

Comment: You're creating an open graph object. Has your OG actions been approved?

Comment: Thanks Ming Li for the suggestion.....i checked and came to know that my OG object also needs approval which i didn't know earlier. i am now resubmitting the app for approval and will update here if it works then.